# iOS: UIView animation ignores delay

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have a problem with very simple `UIView` animation:

```
- (void)showView:(CGFloat)delay
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:delay options:0 animations:^{

        // self.alpha = 0.5; // Works OK with delay
        self.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30); // delay is ignored
    } completion:nil];
}
```

`delay` could be set to `1000` and still view is animated immediately. But somehow it works fine with `alpha` (without setting `frame`).

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @Fogmeister No. Starting animaion from superview also doesn't help

Comment: I have the similar problem. Moving code to -didMoveToSuperview can help with delay, but it is not very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The frame is probably being set for you, perhaps by layout being performed by the superview, or this view itself. You haven't said how you're adding this view or what it does so its difficult to give specific advice, but in general terms:

- Don't let a view be in control of its own frame - this is the superview's or view controllers responsibility. A view can have a preferred size, but the rest is outside.
- it's usually better to animate bounds and / or centre instead of frame, particularly if you're ignoring the first point.
- For presentation type animations, it may be better to animate the transform instead - either translation or scale, depending what your animation is.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animateMe) withObject:nil afterDelay:1000];
```

If `self` is `viewController` then you should use `self.view.frame` instead of `self.frame`. If `self` is `view` then you should use `self.frame`.

```
- (void)animateMe {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

        // self.alpha = 0.5; // Works OK with delay
        self.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30); // delay is ignored
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSLog(@"Done");
    }];            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses Swift, specifically version 4.2, and is tested in Xcode 10 playgrounds. This is actually my first try animating, and I'm very green with iOS in general, but this is how I solved the problem of `delay` not being observed.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Set up the main view
let liveViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let liveView = UIView(frame: liveViewFrame)
liveView.backgroundColor = .white

// Show the live view using the main view
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = liveView

// Set up a smaller view for animation
let smallFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let square = UIView(frame: smallFrame)
square.backgroundColor = .purple

// Add the square to the live view ...
liveView.addSubview(square)

// ... and create an alias for it to allow delays to work.
// Calling square directly won't allow delays,
// giving it or the liveView subview an alias directly fails,
// and unwrapping (? or !) appears to fail as well.
// So, just call like `alias?.backgroundColor` ...
let squareView = square.superview?.subviews[0]

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 1.0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
    //square.backgroundColor = .orange // this doesn't respect the delay arg
    squareView?.backgroundColor = .orange
    squareView?.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200)
    squareView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
}, completion: nil)
```

This may not answer the question directly, but I believe similar logic could be applied for a workaround in related cases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```swift
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.2, 
    delay: 1, 
    options: .curveLinear, 
    animations: {
        self.someButton.isHidden = false
    })
}
```

Do just:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, 
        delay: 0, 
        options: .curveLinear, 
        animations: {
        self.someButton.isHidden = false
    })
}
```